# Navigation Bar not selectable in Show Segue, Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6

There are 2 View Controllers in my storyboard, **VC_A** and **VC_B**

I have embeded a navigation controller in **VC_A** which is a Table View Controller, I then control drag the Prototype Cell into **VC_B** to create a segue. If I select `"show"` in "selection segue" then in **VC_B** I can see the outline of the navigation bar but I am unable to select it or add any bar buttons to it, it also doesn't appear in the hierarchical view.

[image: view]

However if I select the `"push (deprecated)"` option when choosing the type of segue, I am able to select the navigation bar in **VC_B** and add buttons to it, it also show up in the hierarchical view as a Navigation Item.

The only work around I can find is to choose `show`, then change the segue to `push(deprecated)` in the Attribute Inspector so the Navigation Item will show up in the hierarchical view, then change the segue back to `show`. But I am worry that this might cause problems further down the line.

Is there a way to add a Bar Button to **VC_B**'s navigation bar without using the work around?

Comment: Running into the same issue. Don't have a work-around. Although you can just start with push(deprecated) and then go to show.

Answer (score 13):

Just drag the "Navigation Item" from object library to the navigation bar and it should work as expected. You can make changes as you like and it works exactly like in Xcode 5.

Comment: This does not seem to be working for me on Xcode 6.1.1.

Comment: This is correct. With size classes a navigation item isn't automatically added to a view controller, even if they are coming from a controller which is root view controller of a nav controller. I don't think this is a bug. A said controller may or may not be presented from a nav controller (check up on size classes).

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly, when you first time made the connection b/w your **table view controller** and **view controller** using **Push** you can start editing the navigation bar without a problem (e.g put bar items onto it).

Then delete the connection between your **table view controller** and **view controller** (but do not delete the nav bar items you just added), then re-connect the two controllers by using segue **Show**, you will see the navigation bar works just like segue **Push** now.

Hope it helps

Comment: This is a good solution, except you don't have to delete anything just make a `[Deprecated] Push` segue and then change it to a new `Show` one.

Answer (score 6):

I think the way you do it (going through  the deprecated push) is not wrong even though there's another way. In fact, when you turn the Segue into a push, you get a Navigation Item out of it.

So all you have to do is add a Navigation Item to your View Controller and that'll do the trick:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This seems Xcode bugs.

In my case, i am re-create segue by this sequence:

1. Delete existing seque. (I am using "Action segue - Show")
2. Drag new segue with "Non-Adaptive Action Segue - Push (deprecated)"
3. Delete segue no.2
4. Re-create/connect "Action Seque - Show". (No.1)
5. Done

Now, i can edit navigation title and add custom navigation item button as usually.

I am using Xcode 6.4, and minimal target iOS version 7.

Answer (score 3):

In your viewController :

```
self.navigationItem.title = "Second VC"
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "playFunction:")
```

[image]

Comment: I think the point is that they want to keep this stuff in the storyboard.